# SQL Server permissions to create arbitrary custom-types and stored procedures with them

Tags: sql-server, permissions

What are the most restrictive permissions to allow for creation of arbitrary custom types and stored procedures with use the types in SQL Server?

For instance:

```
create type dbo.MyType as table (dt: DateTime2, primary key clustered (dt asc))
go
create procedure dbo.MyProcedure
@input dbo.MyType readonly
as
begin
  print 'done'
end
```

Comment: [Requires `CREATE TYPE` permission in the current database and `ALTER` permission on schema_name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions)

Comment: ```
grant alter on schema::dbo to test;
grant create type to test;
```
Doesn't work.
Keep getting "Could not find the type 'dbo.MyType'. Either it does not exist or you do not have the necessary permission"

Comment: @DanKo Your comment is unclear: how, exactly, did you get that messages about _"Could not find the type"_ ? You won't get it just from running the `GRANT ALTER...` and `GRANT CREATE...` statements... so you're missing out a lot of repro steps and details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is the absolute minimum privileges, but I recently needed to grant a `ROLE` the ability to run `CREATE TYPE` (and `DROP TYPE`) within a T-SQL batch (for some gnarly Dynamic-SQL process; no `PROCEDURE` objects are involved though).

This worked for me (in SSMS; if you're running this manually, split this file up into [separate batches between the `GO` delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql)):

(The `FoobarLogin` and `FoobarUser` are included for illustrative purposes)

```sql
USE master;

CREATE LOGIN FoobarLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'PasswordGoesHere';

GO

USE MyDatabase;

CREATE USER FoobarUser FROM LOGIN FoobarLogin;

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'FoobarUser';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'FoobarUser';

CREATE ROLE me_typescreator;

GRANT EXECUTE TO me_typescreator;
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA ::dbo TO me_typescreator;
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO me_typescreator;

GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'me_typescreator', @membername = 'FoobarUser';
```